# Calling Microsoft Graph APIs as authenticated user from an ASP.net Core WebApp that uses AzureAD authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I have a Asp.NET Core MVC 2.2 WebApp that uses Azure Active Directory to log-in users, configured like this:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services){
    //...

    services.AddAuthentication(AzureADDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddAzureAD(options => configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options));

    //...
}
```

All the required info is configured in `appsettings.json` (ClientID, TenantID, domain, etc.) and the login process works perfectly without issues.

Now, when the user calls a certain action in a certain controller, I would like to make a few calls to the Microsoft Graph API. As I understand, since I'm already logged in as an authenticated AzureAD user, this *should* not be a problem, since I should be able to set the required `Delgated` permissions and then use an instance of `GraphServiceClient` (from the `Microsoft.Graph` library) to make the calls:

```
[HttpGet("[action]")]
public IActionResult Test()
{
    GraphServiceClient graphClient = GetGraphServiceClient(); //HOW????

    //... make calls etc.

    return Ok("OK");
}
```

The problem is that, when searching online, I got completely lost on HOW to obtain a authenticated instance of `GraphServiceClient`. I found several samples, but all using completely different approaches, and often requiring dozens of extra classes and support methods. Is it really that complicated?

So my question is, what is the best/simplest way to call the Microsoft Graph API in my scenario? To recap:

- I need to call the Graph API from an action method in one of my
  controllers
- The user will always be authenticated when the call is
  made, and the delegated permissions are properly set in the AzureAD
  console, so all that is needed (in theory) is to obtain a working
  graph client

Can someone provide a minimal sample?

Comment: Almost 2 years later and I find myself wondering the same thing: Where is a code sample that uses `GraphServiceClient` in conjunction with `services.AddAzureAD(...)`?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `GraphServiceClient` like this:

```
   var accessToken = "";
    var graphserviceClient = new GraphServiceClient(
    new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(
    (requestMessage) =>
    {
        requestMessage.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }));
```

Here is the [aspnetcore sample](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/2-WebApp-graph-user/2-1-Call-MSGraph) for your reference.

**Update:**

> That's why I've asked if there was a more straightforward way.

Yes, there is. You can choose the appropriate authentication provider [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS) to create the GraphServiceClient.

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but now the question becomes "how do I get the accessToken?". The sample you linked is the one I was using before, which uses quite a few extra classes and methods (you basically have to import the entire source from Microsoft.Identity.Web to make it work). That's why I've asked if there was a more straightforward way... I guess there isn't?

Comment: Thanks for the support, but this doesn't work form me. I've tried with the `OnBehalfOfProvider` (it seemed like the correct one for my scenario), but if I try to make a request with the GraphServiceClient it throws a NullReferenceException during the call, with no other details.